# it's better to add error for each state in redux react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state, loading

it's better to add loading (or error) state for each reducer state in redux !!
or just using in one reducer ??

Exemple : put loading in state reducer category and state reducer Product

```
const initialState = {
    products : [],
    loading : true ,
    error : null
}

const categsReducer = (state = initialState,action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
```

```
const initialState = {
    categories : [],
    loading : true ,
    idCategStore : null,
    error : null
}

const categsReducer = (state = initialState,action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
```

or using loading in one reducer state ??

Comment: redux store is basically used to store global data of an app. 
usually, loading and error states are associated with a component. With the little information that you provided here in question, I do not understand why you want to include loading and error in initial state for redux

Comment: so where should i include them?

Comment: you should include laoding and error states associated with a component within itself

Comment: How do you fetch the data, are you using thunk actions? If you let the component fetch the data and store result in local state then that's fine but if other components need that data as well then you're not. You could add data type to the action and then the reducer can set `state.data[action.payload.dataType]`, no repeating logic.